# How to access a SpriteBatchNode from another class? cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm having trouble getting my sprite batch node to work and it's partly because I don't understand the concept complete. The SpriteFrameCache is shared, which makes it easy to access, but the SpriteBatchNode isn't so I don't know the best way to access it from another class.

I have my sprite batch node set up as an instance variable in my main GameplayLayer.m:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"MyTexture.plist"];
spriteBatchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"MyTexture.png"];
```

But then I have a Monster class with animations set up inside the class but the sprites are in the texture that was created in my GameplayLayer class:

```
CCAnimation *walkAnim = [CCAnimation animation];
[walkAnim addSpriteFrame:[spriteFrameCache spriteFrameByName:@"monster-sprite-walk0.png"]];
//some other code
self.monsterWalkAnimation = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:walkAnimationAction];
```

Which doesn't work, I'm guessing because it has no idea where the texture is. What is the best way to access that sprite batch node, or am I setting this up all wrong?

Comment: "doesn't work" meaning what? Error message? Observation? PS: this might be helpful: http://www.koboldtouch.com/display/IDCAR/Strategies+for+Accessing+Other+Nodes

Comment: Error message: *** Assertion failure in -[Monster setTexture:]

Comment: Is it perhaps telling you that the sprite frame's texture isn't the same texture as the sprite batch node? You can only add sprites to the batch node which use the same texture as the sprite batch node.

Comment: ^this I don't understand. The difference in terminology is throwing me for a loop. I created a Texture Atlas in Texture Packer and put the plist and png into my main layer called MyTexture.png and in that texture is definitely the sprite image file "monster-sprite-walk0.png". Is this what you mean by texture?

Comment: post the assertion message, the other one would be a nil texture. If you're sure the frame name (monster...) and batch node texture are the same, then perhaps you have the same frame name in another texture atlas as well?

Comment: Unfortunately that's all it says in the log, *** Assertion failure in -[Monster setTexture:]

Comment: enable global exception breakpoint in Xcode, then you'll see the error message and Xcode will show you the offending line of code

Comment: Well that's a useful debugging trick I should have but didn't know about. Here's the line, under the setTexture method: NSAssert( !batchNode_ || texture.name == batchNode_.texture.name , @"CCSprite: Batched sprites should use the same texture as the batchnode");